# Matplotlib center axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm generating several graphs with two y-axises using Matplotlib.

On each graph I'm drawing a horizontal line with `plt.axhline` (`hline` herein). The scale of my graphs vary, but they all start at `hline`, so I want both of the y axises of my graphs to be centered around `hline`.  Is there any way to give my axises a `ylim`, but instead of specifying the `min` and `max` values, I specify a `center` value?

Right now, I have to parse through all the lines to find an equal amount above and below `hline` to set `ylim`, but this method is super tedious and time consuming.

This is what I have (note the secondary axis - `hline` doesn't pass through 1):
[image]

And this is what I want (note both axises have `hline` passing through 1):
[image]